# Want to use drive vertex weightings

Tags: drivers, vertex-weights

I would like to reduce the proportional weights of vertices on a Vertex Group as a bone grows distant from another bone.   An example would be to somehow use a function that would return a vertex weight in a group based on a bone distance calculation.

[image]

Blender-exchange is working today!  [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we want to scale down the values of a particular group of vertices, dynamically, we can do that with a vertex weight edit modifier:

[image]

Here, all vertices are fully assigned to Group, which is used to modulate a shrinkwrap modifier.  However, I can reduce the weights of that group to 0 by using a custom curve that's just a straight line at y=0.

It's not going all the way to zero-- we have some shrinkwrapping going on-- because I have set the global influence of my vertex weight edit modifier to 0.5ish.  So all my weights are interpolating halfway between 1 and 0.

If we want, we can use a driver to control this influence, same as most properties in Blender.  We can set the driver to be using a "distance" type variable, at which point we can nominate two bones in the armature for that distance calculation:

[image]

Here, the distance between the bones is about 0.3, so we're only scaling away 30% of our weights, and we can adjust this dynamically.

This would work just as well for evaluating weights of bones in an armature, that are evaluated in an armature modifier that follows the vertex weight edit.  Note that we are not renormalizing our other weights, but Blender renormalizes implicitly for an armature modifier.

[image]

Here, dearest Suzanne is weighted equally to Bone and Group, but because Bone.001 is more than 1 unit away from Bone, all weights to Group are destroyed by the vertex weight edit modifier, leaving only weights to Bone.

Note that there are any number of ways to do this, ranging from equally simple (geometry nodes, or driving our curve's Y position instead) to bizarrely Goldbergesque (data transferring vertex weight proximity from two non-rendering meshes parented to our bones and using that as part of a vertex weight mix.)

Comment: The incredible Nathan to the rescue